# Deleting text from Map Items in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I have been using QGIS for some time, and what I am experiencing is not something that I have had issues with before. It appears to be a gitch.

I created a map in QGIS 3.6.2. Then, I exported it as a new print layout in the print composer. At some point during the creation of a print layout, I was working with text labels to create a north arrow/final touches, and didn't notice the random symbology that was created in the map item (see photo). Now, it appears I cannot select these symbols to delete them and they appear when I close and reopen print composer and even when I restart QGIS and export a new print layout from my original map. They appear to auto generate, but I cannot seem to be able to select them. Again, they are not in the original QGIS map, only in the print composer/map layout.

How do I remove these text label errors that are somehow embedded in my print layouts?

[image: strange text/symbols in qgis map layout that I cannot select or delete]